# Php PEAR and outlook.office365.com imap

Tags: email, office365, pear

I am trying to connect to outlook application of office365 using the php PEAR framework. Below are the details of imap
IMAP Host: outlook.office365.com
IMAP Port: 993
Encryption: SSL
IMAP Username: (my Office365 username)
IMAP Password: (my Office365 password)

But i am unable to establish connection to it. Firewall for the port 993 is already opened from the server i am trying. Can someone help me where i am going wrong.

Error:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => 1
            [params] =>
            [package] => Mail_IMAPv2
            [level] => error
            [time] => 1543397738.02
            [context] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /app/lib/PEAR/Mail/IMAPv2.php
                    [line] => 713
                    [function] => connect
                    [class] => Mail_IMAPv2
                )

```
        [message] => Unable to build a connection to the specified mail server.
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Our old Imap connection looks like this

```
imap://{$user}:{$pass}@hostname:port/{$Folder}#notls
```

We have replaced this format using php inbuilt function

```
imap_open("{hostname:port/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/authuser=$user/user=$user}", $user ,$pass);
```

It is working for us now.